# Генерация отчета в формате PDF на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Необходимо, на основе анализа данных, создавать отчет в формате pdf. В отчете содержатся таблицы и комментарии. Какие библиотеки и инструменты можно использовать для заполнения отчета(создание таблиц, редактирование текста, заливка цветом определенных ячеек таблиц) и сохранении его в формате PDF.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Неужели поисковики не помогли вам с поиском нужно библиотеки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python-pdf - генерация pdf по html шаблону.

Установка

```
pip3 install python-pdf
```

И запуск

```
import pydf
pdf = pydf.generate_pdf('<h1>this is html</h1>')
with open('test_doc.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdf)
```

Сам шаблон можно сгенерировать через jinja2